# running dialog in onPostExecute Asynctask

Tags: android

i have onPostExecute in Asynctask

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        TextView tvStatus=(TextView) layoutSendDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPupukSendStatus);
        if (bNodata){
            tvStatus.setText("No data to be sent!!!");              
        }else {
            if (bError){
                tvStatus.setText("Fail at record #"+String.format("%d",recordCount));
            }
            else {
                tvStatus.setText("Sending Data : Finished");
                CUtilities.showAlert(CInputHamaApp.this, "Data Terkirim");
                createDialogSend2();
                // Closing dashboard screen
            }
        }
//          dismissDialog(CGeneral.DIALOG_SEND);
    }
```

here is my dialog

```
private Dialog createDialogSend2(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CInputHamaApp.this);
    builder.setMessage("Anda yakin untuk update?");
    builder.setTitle("Warning") ;
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(CInputHamaApp.this, CInputHamaApp.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            // do nothing – it will close on its own
            }
            });
    return builder.create();        
}//createDialogSend2
```

i put `createDialogSend2();` in this onPostExecute code

```
           else {
                    tvStatus.setText("Sending Data : Finished");
                    CUtilities.showAlert(CInputHamaApp.this, "Data Terkirim");
                    createDialogSend2();
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                }
```

but the result is when the status is finished the dialog show alert only, and `createDialogSend2();` not running.

how to show `createDialogSend2()` when text send Data is finished

BR

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't `show()` the dialog. you need something like...

```
AlertDialog dlg = createDialogSend2();
dlg.show();
```

Comment: when i try error in eclipse `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dialog to AlertDialog` @David M

Comment: the return type of your function should be `AlertDialog` not `Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();    
alert.show();
```

Add this in your `createDialogSend2()`

Comment: i try to put your code in createDialogSend2() disable yes, but the dialog not show.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, in OnPostExecute Method.

I add Activity object as propretie in my AsyncTask Class  which I instantiate in the constructor of that AsyncTack so that I can call that activity and perform runOnUiThread in  onpostexe...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            builder.setTitle("Connection ?");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setMessage("Test \n ");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",null);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            Activity.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    //show AlertDialog
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
```